# Node JS compliant function to search any object and return the property and value

Tags: javascript, node.js

Was looking for a Node JS compliant function to search any object for property and/or value as string and return all matches for the property and/or value as array.

Did not find anything so I made my own so I thought I would share. Feel free to find flaws and state them... let's make this good! Also, if there are any existing tools for doing this better, let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: Search for *what*? And what exactly does it return? What is the requirement?

Comment: Searching for a specific string as parameter or value or either. EDITED

Answer (score -1):

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/iomatrix/gebz6swm/1/

usage:

```js
try{
    let results = contains( object, string1, {match: "VALUE", cs: true, exact: true } )
    results = contains( results, string2, { match: "ANY", cs: true, exact: true } )
}
catch(err){
    console.log( "Catching errors is important :): " + err.stack ) );
}
```

Function is recursive to delve deep. It will return and array of all matches with `{property: value}` pair and it's parent. At this point it only has string matching but could be expanded to include other data types for matching.

Result can be chained (see above) to filter to specifically desired components.

```js
    function contains( o, s, options={}, result=[]){ //OPTION CAN BE "PROPERTY", "VALUE", or default("ANY") 
    //Returns array of results
    //options etc:  {match: "ANY"/"PROPERTY"/"VALUE", cs: true/false, exact: true/false}

    let match = options.match ? options.match : "ANY";
    let cs = options.cs ? options.cs : false;
    let exact = options.exact ? options.exact : false;

    let match_any = (match.toUpperCase() == "ANY") ? true : false;
    let match_property = (match.toUpperCase() == "PROPERTY") ? true : false;
    let match_value = (match.toUpperCase() == "VALUE") ? true : false;

    //IS OBJECT?
    if (typeof o === 'object'){
        if(Array.isArray(o)){

            //Iterate Array, IF Value is Object, recurse to contains
            for(const e of o){

                if (typeof e === 'object'){
                    contains(e,s,options, result);
                }
                else{
                    if (cs){
                        if(exact){
                            if( ( match_any || match_value ) && String(e) == String(s) ){
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                result.push(e);
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            if( ( match_any || match_value ) && String(e).includes(String(s)) ){
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                result.push(e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if(exact){
                            if( ( match_any || match_value ) && String(e).toLowerCase() == String(s).toLowerCase()  ){
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                result.push(e);
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            if( ( match_any || match_value ) && String(e).toLowerCase().includes( String(s).toLowerCase() ) ){
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                result.push(e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        else{
            //Iterate Object, IF Value is Object, recurse to contains
            for (const p in o){

                if(typeof o[p] === 'object'){
                    if (cs){
                        if(exact){
                            if(  (match_any || match_property) && String(p) == String(s)  ){
                                let obj = {}
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                obj[p] = o[p];
                                result.push(obj);  
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            if(  (match_any || match_property) && String(p).includes(String(s))){
                                let obj = {}
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                obj[p] = o[p];
                                result.push(obj);  
                            }
                        }
                        contains(o[p],s, options, result);
                    }
                    else{
                        if(exact){
                            if(  (match_any || match_property) && String(p).toLowerCase() == String(s).toLowerCase() ){
                                let obj = {}
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                obj[p] = o[p];
                                result.push(obj);  
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            if(  (match_any || match_property) && String(p).toLowerCase().includes( String(s).toLowerCase() )){
                                let obj = {}
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                obj[p] = o[p];
                                result.push(obj);  
                            }
                        }
                        contains(o[p],s, options, result);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if (cs){
                        if(exact){
                            if( (match_any || match_property)  &&  String(p) == String(s) ){
                                let obj = {}
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                obj[p] = o[p];
                                result.push(obj);
                            }
                            if( (match_any || match_value) && String(o[p]) == String(s)  ){
                                let obj = {}
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                obj[p] = o[p];
                                result.push(obj);
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            if( (match_any || match_property)  &&  String(p).includes(String(s)) ){
                                let obj = {}
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                obj[p] = o[p];
                                result.push(obj);
                            }
                            if( (match_any || match_value) && String(o[p]).includes(String(s))){
                                let obj = {}
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                obj[p] = o[p];
                                result.push(obj);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if(exact){
                            if( (match_any || match_property)  &&  String(p).toLowerCase() == String(s).toLowerCase() ){
                                let obj = {}
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                obj[p] = o[p];
                                result.push(obj);
                            }
                            if( (match_any || match_value) && String(o[p]).toLowerCase() == String(s).toLowerCase() ){
                                let obj = {}
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                obj[p] = o[p];
                                result.push(obj);
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            if( (match_any || match_property)  &&  String(p).toLowerCase().includes( String(s).toLowerCase() )){
                                let obj = {}
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                obj[p] = o[p];
                                result.push(obj);
                            }
                            if( (match_any || match_value) && String(o[p]).toLowerCase().includes( String(s).toLowerCase() )){
                                let obj = {}
                                obj["parent"] = o;
                                obj[p] = o[p];
                                result.push(obj);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    else{
        if (cs){
            if(exact){
                if( (match_any || match_value) && String(o) == String(s) ){
                    obj["parent"] = o;
                    result.push(o);
                }
            }
            else{
                if( (match_any || match_value) && String(o).includes(String(s))){
                    obj["parent"] = o;
                    result.push(o);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        else{
            if(exact){
                if( (match_any || match_value) && String(o).toLowerCase() ==  String(s).toLowerCase() ){
                    obj["parent"] = o;
                    result.push(o);
                }
            }
            else{
                if( (match_any || match_value) && String(o).toLowerCase().includes( String(s).toLowerCase() )){
                    obj["parent"] = o;
                    result.push(o);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Function is async*" why? In general, this seems like it belong on [codereview.se]

Comment: Plans are to use it to receive object from DB so I made it that way. I'll take a look at Code Review. Thank you VLAZ

Comment: Bravo... can you help me understand what you mean? I am using this function successfully on a large JSON parsed object. It is able to search the resulting array. This is also why I made it async.... I just find it an easier syntax vs save result then reuse result etc.

Comment: Everyone seems VERY focused that this returns a promise. I realize there is no external resource required ATM and async is redundant. I will remove the async in my answer and see if there are more useful points to consider

Comment: Bravo, have a look and tell me what I am missing... http://jsfiddle.net/iomatrix/gebz6swm/